# I'm not able to validate my ipa from command line but it work from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, terminal

I'm trying to validate my app by command line using this :

```
xcrun altool --validate-app -f myapp.ipa -t ios -u "id" -p
```

But I'm getting this error :

> altool[1043:29194] *** Error: Unable to validate archive 'myapp.ipa':
>   ( "Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-21017 "Could
>   not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a
>   CFBundleIdentifier in 'myapp.ipa'."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find the main bundle or the
>   Info.plist is missing a CFBundleIdentifier in 'myapp.ipa'.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}" )

I exported an IPA from Xcode, directly in Xcode I can validate and upload it but I don't understand this error when I'm trying to do it from the command line

Comment: Are you in the correct folder when running that command?

Comment: Yes I'm on the correct folder, if I'm not on the good one I receive this error :

altool[961:8047] *** Error: Unable to validate archive 'myapp.ipa': (
    "Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-21013 "The archive is invalid. myapp.ipa does not exist." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The archive is invalid. myapp.ipa does not exist., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"

Comment: The "myapp.ipa does not exist" bit seems important...

Comment: Yes it mean there is no myapp.ipa when I'm in the wrong folder but when I'm on the good one a got the error you can see on the first post

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like the `.ipa` file is completely broken though.  What does it say when you run `file myapp.ipa`?